# How to show that points in a set are interior point?

Tags: real-analysis

Let A$\subset$$\mathbb{R}$ and u be an interior point of A. Show that there is a neighbourhood V of u such that each point in V is an interior point of A.

I'm not really sure how to start. Do I have to show that V is open?

Comment: Yes, that will do nicely.

Comment: I think before someone asked what definition of interior point I was using: Let A$\subset$$\mathbb{R}$. A real number u is an interior point of A if there is $\epsilon$>0 such that B(u,$\epsilon$)$\subset$A.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brian

Comment: The neighbourhood you need is $B(u,\epsilon)$ (for an arbitrary $x\in B(u,\varepsilon),$ take $\delta:=\epsilon-|x-u|,$ so that $B(x,\delta)\subseteq B(u,\epsilon)\subseteq A$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $u\in A^{\circ}$, there exists a $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(u)\subset A$.

Let $x\in B_{r}(u)$. Assume that $z\in V:=B_{s}(x)$, then $d(x,z)<s$.

Choose $0<s\leq r-d(x,u)$ (... ask yourself why). Prove that $d(u,z)<r$.

Conclude that $z\in B_{r}(u)$.